# ruby on rails rails new error gem install ffi -v

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffi

good day
Today starting to study ruby on rails I find this error when creating a new application

/Users/Manux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/ffi-1.9.17/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.17), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.17'` succeeds before bundling.

I use ruby-2.1.1 and rails 5.0.1

Comment: brew install libffi ( see on stackoverflow ) ....Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.

Comment: Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/Manux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ffi-1.9.17 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/Manux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/ffi-1.9.17/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.17), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.17'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: I update ruby to Rails version: 5.0.1
Ruby version: 2.2.2 (x86_64-darwin14) and the problem continues

Comment: What do the logs say when you try a `gem install ffi -v '1.9.17'` ?

Comment: Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/Manux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Manux/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170115-3059-xl84x5.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.

Comment: Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Manux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ffi-1.9.17 for inspection.

Comment: Try some commands: `pkg-config libffi --cflags --libs` (my Mac 10.12.2 says: "-I/usr/local/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -L/usr/local/lib -lffi") - another test could be: `find /usr -name libffi*`

Comment: Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found

Comment: /usr/local/Library/Formula/libffi.rb
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied

Comment: Try to reinstall libffi (do a brew update before)

Comment: Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull --quiet origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: Apparently it was a dependency of xcode, which was not updated when upgrading the operating system.
Reinstalling xcode solved the problem.Thanks @matt